# VBA runtime error 91 with .xlsm file but not .xlsx

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

My program works as intended with non macro excel files but for whatever reason when I try to use it with macro workbooks it gives me run time error 91. The variable doesn't look like it loads anything into the Fname when it is a macro book. I suspect this may be because the company settings are for the user to enable macros on use. This snippet seems to fail to load the file path for macro books.

```
Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="XLS Files (*.xls),*.xls,XLSM Files (*.xlsm),*.xlsm", _
    Title:="Select a workbook", _
    MultiSelect:=False)

SheetName = Application.InputBox("Please enter the name of the output tab", , , , , , , 2)

pulled = sh1.Range("B1:B30")
WSoutputs = sh1.Range("B1:B30")

sh4.Range("J1:J28").ClearContents
Set sh2 = Workbooks.Open(Fname)
```

Is there a way to read the data from a macrobook without needing to enable it? If not how would I prompt the user to open the file like normal and hit enable macros?

Full Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Pull()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Workbook
Dim sh3 As Worksheet
Dim sh4 As Worksheet
Dim Path As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim arg As String
Dim pulled
Dim WSoutputs
Dim Comp(30, 0) As Variant
Dim Fname As Variant
Dim SheetName

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Refs")
Set sh3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")
Set sh4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Inputs")

On Error GoTo Err:

Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="XLS Files (*.xls),*.xls,XLSM Files (*.xlsm),*.xlsm,XLSX Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx", _
    Title:="Select a workbook", _
    MultiSelect:=False)

SheetName = Application.InputBox("Please enter the name of the output tab", , , , , , , 2)

pulled = sh1.Range("B1:B30")
WSoutputs = sh1.Range("B1:B30")

sh4.Range("J1:J28").ClearContents
Set sh2 = Workbooks.Open(Fname)



For i = (LBound(pulled) + 2) To UBound(pulled)
    pulled(i, 1) = Trim(pulled(i, 1))
    pulled(i, 1) = sh2.Sheets(SheetName).Range(pulled(i, 1))
    WSoutputs(i, 1) = sh3.Range(WSoutputs(i, 1))
    If pulled(i, 1) = WSoutputs(i, 1) Then
        Comp(i - 3, 0) = "Match"
    Else
        Comp(i - 3, 0) = pulled(i, 1)
    End If
Next i
sh2.Close

sh4.Range("J1:J28") = Comp

Exit Sub

Err:
MsgBox ("Make sure the Workbook and tab names are correct. Make sure the output format matches this workbook")
sh4.Range("J1:J28").ClearContents
If Fname <> "False.xlsx" Or Fname <> "False.xlsm" Then
    sh2.Close
End If
End Sub
```

The loop doesn't seem to do what I want as somewhere in it Sh2 becomes empty. Also, pulled and Wsoutput contain cell references (ex B3) and the input and output format are the same between worksheets.

Comment: `GetOpenFilename` doesn't open the file, so something else is the problem if `Fname` has no value. When using `GetOpenFilename` you should always check the return value is not `False` before trying to open the selected workbook.  BTW if you have xls**m** files wouldn't you also be looking for xls**x** files?

Comment: Posted full code. The file I was working with was xls, but yes I wanted xlsx too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this, but you should post as much code as possible.  I do not know how the following are defined.  Try this anyhow.

```
Set pulled = sh1.Range("B1:B30")
Set WSoutputs = sh1.Range("B1:B30")
```